# How to mount HDFS 2.7.1 on CentOS 7?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, mount, fuse

I try to figure out how to mount HDFS 2.7.1 but without success. What is the right way to mount it like a local file system? I already have an HDFS running cluster.

Answer (score -1):

HDFS support is absolutely not default in Hadoop distribution(s) nor Linux distros.

You have to google for "hdfs fuse", install and run yourself.

https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS